# how do you add PHP values from a form?

Tags: php, mysql, math, addition

I am trying to add my PHP values. They are all integer numbers.

I have all the values out however I need to calculate a total for all of them.

My code is:

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="hmpperth";

$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$nationalnumber=$_POST['nationalnumber'];
$rad1=$_POST['rad1'];
$rad2=$_POST['rad2'];
$rad3=$_POST['rad3'];
$rad4=$_POST['rad4'];
$rad5=$_POST['rad5'];
$rad6=$_POST['rad6'];
$rad7=$_POST['rad7'];
$rad8=$_POST['rad8'];
$rad9=$_POST['rad9'];
$rad10=$_POST['rad10'];
$rad11=$_POST['rad11'];
$rad12=$_POST['rad12'];
$rad13=$_POST['rad13'];
$rad14=$_POST['rad14'];
$rad15=$_POST['rad15'];
$rad16=$_POST['rad16'];
$rad17=$_POST['rad17'];
$rad18=$_POST['rad18'];
$rad1 + $rad2 + $rad3 + $rad4 + $rad5 + $rad6 + $rad7 + $rad8 + $rad9 + $rad10 + $rad11 + $rad12 + $rad13 + $rad14 + $rad15 + $rad16 + $rad17 + $rad18=$_POST['totalscore'];


mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO testb VALUES ('','$surname','$nationalnumber','$rad1','$rad2','$rad3','$rad4','$rad5','$rad6','$rad7','$rad8','$rad9','$rad10','$rad11','$rad12','$rad13','$rad14','$rad15','$rad16','$rad17','$rad18','$rad1 + $rad2 + $rad3 + $rad4 + $rad5 + $rad6 + $rad7 + $rad8 + $rad9 + $rad10 + $rad11 + $rad12 + $rad13 + $rad14 + $rad15 + $rad16 + $rad17 + $rad18')";
mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Comment: and your present results are what exactly? errors if any?

Comment: Well, `$rad1 + $rad2 + $rad3 + $rad4 + $rad5 + $rad6 + $rad7 + $rad8 + $rad9 + $rad10 + $rad11 + $rad12 + $rad13 + $rad14 + $rad15 + $rad16 + $rad17 + $rad18=$_POST['totalscore'];` is backwards.

Comment: At the moment, my total is '3' which is the the value that has been inputted for 'rad1'. So I'm guessing it is not adding my other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assign the total variable and your query is wrong because the single quotes will not add the values in the way you are thinking.

Change this:

```
$rad1 + $rad2 + $rad3 + $rad4 + $rad5 + $rad6 + $rad7 + $rad8 + $rad9 + $rad10 + $rad11 + $rad12 + $rad13 + $rad14 + $rad15 + $rad16 + $rad17 + $rad18=$_POST['totalscore'];
```

To this - variables are defined from the left-hand side not the right (programming is not similar to math equations):

```
$totalscore = $rad1 + $rad2 + $rad3 + $rad4 + $rad5 + $rad6 + $rad7 + $rad8 + $rad9 + $rad10 + $rad11 + $rad12 + $rad13 + $rad14 + $rad15 + $rad16 + $rad17 + $rad18;
```

Change your insert query to use the new `$totalscore` variable - because the variable is a number, you do need to use single quotes to insert it:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO testb VALUES ('','$surname','$nationalnumber','$rad1','$rad2','$rad3','$rad4','$rad5','$rad6','$rad7','$rad8','$rad9','$rad10','$rad11','$rad12','$rad13','$rad14','$rad15','$rad16','$rad17','$rad18', $totalscore)";
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO SO SO MUCH I LOVE YOU